# jNews installation giving database error in Joomla! 3

Tags: joomla3.0, joomla-component

I have `jNews` installed in my Joomla! 3 site then I tried to install `jNews 8.2.1` which is giving following **SQL** error:

```
SQL=SELECT `akey` FROM `j17_acajoom_xonfig`
```

After this error occurred, all other option of `jNews` is working fine EXCEPT **Configuration**. Once i clicked on **Configuration**, it returned with the same **SQL** error! No idea how o fix this!

Any help?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem arise if you **update** your existing `jNews` to newer version because there is no **table** named `j17_acajoom_xonfig` in newer version.

you'll need to **rename** your **DB** table name.

Comment: hi, it's been a long time since i've posted this question here & didn't get any answer that time. thanks for your answer, although i've figured that out but didn't come back here & posted it. thanks again, i'll upvote you :)

Comment: you must have posted that what you've figured out earlier:)